# JAXB mapping null-lists to empty collections?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I have a webservice soap service that takes an object with an optional list as xml parameter:

```
@XmlElement(required = false)
private List<String> list;

public List<String> getList() { return list; }
```

Is it possible to tell JAXB to always return/use an empty collection instead of a `null` list if the list tag is not provided by the client?

Or will I always have to define a lazy getter on the server side for list that should never be null (I'd prefer this to be always the case)?

```
public List<String> getList() {
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want the absence of the collection from the XML to correspond to an empty `List` in the Java object you just need to do the following.

```
@XmlElement(required = false)
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This will marshal the same as if the field was `null`.  There is only a difference in how a `null` and empty `List` is marshalled when the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation is used.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html

Comment: Update: 'required = false' is now the default when using @XmlElement.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the empty tag to be present, then either initialize with in getter as it is shown by you.

or

```
@XmlElement(required = false)
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

So that the tag would be present.